# LINQ to XML just pickup child elements not lower same named elements

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I'm using VB.net axis notation to walk some returned XML.

The XML has a list of "type" nodes that I need in a list.

[image]

It also has some other "type" nodes further down in the XML that I'm not interested at this time.

My code:

```
 Dim locTypeList = ""

                For Each locationType In returnedXMLGoogle...<result>...<type>
                    locTypeList = locTypeList & locationType.Value & ","
                Next

                If locTypeList.Length > 0 Then locTypeList = Left(locTypeList, Len(locTypeList) - 1)

                'gpr.googlePlacesTypes = returnedXMLGoogle...<type>.Value

                 gpr.googlePlacesTypes = locTypeList
```

Unfortunately it picks up every child node in the datastructure even ones further down.

[image]

How can I limit the loop to just those nodes under `<result>` node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the child tag instead of the descendants tag:

```
returnedXMLGoogle...<result>.<type>
```

Instead of

`returnedXMLGoogle...<result>...<type>`

This will give you only those type nodes directly anchored to the result node.

Comment: Dim results As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants("result").Descendants("value").ToList()